# Create a trigger from select statement

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a trigger where the data in a column is created/updated when there is an update/insert into the database. I have a column called `topic` and it should be populated with values from other columns. I am able to populate the `topic` column using a `select` statement, but I'm not sure how the syntax is in a trigger to get the same result.

Here is my `SELECT` statement:

```
select 
    name, city, topic, 
    name + ' - ' + city + ' - '+ 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_car = 'yes' THEN 'Car,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_bus = 'yes' THEN 'TBus,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_bike = 'yes' THEN 'Bike,'ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_train = 'yes' THEN 'Train,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_truck = 'yes' THEN 'Truck,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_boat = 'yes' THEN 'Boat,'ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_walk = 'yes' THEN 'Walk,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_motorbike = 'yes' THEN 'Motor Bike, ' ELSE ''
       END AS topic
from 
    dbo.myTableView
```

Thanks

EDIT 1 :
The above `SELECT` statement was querying using a `VIEW`, but the actual columns that were being queried  are from different tables.

Table 1(topicTable):

```
name|topic|new_car|new_bus|new_bike|new_train|new_truck|new_boat|new_walk|new_motorbike
```

Table 2(Addresstable):

```
street1|street2|street3|city|state|zipcode|country
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create trigger on the table for insert and update operations:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggrName
ON tableName AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE t SET topic =  
    name + ' - ' + city + ' - '+ 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_car = 'yes' THEN 'Car,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_bus = 'yes' THEN 'TBus,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_bike = 'yes' THEN 'Bike,'ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_train = 'yes' THEN 'Train,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_truck = 'yes' THEN 'Truck,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_boat = 'yes' THEN 'Boat,'ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_walk = 'yes' THEN 'Walk,' ELSE '' 
       END + 
       CASE 
          WHEN new_motorbike = 'yes' THEN 'Motor Bike, ' ELSE ''
       END    
    FROM tableName t
    JOIN INSERTED i ON t.ID = i.ID

END
```

Comment: im getting an error saying  'invalid column name:city', `city` is in a different table , how would I reference that?

Comment: And where is the city? Join on that diffrent table. Or provide table structues. How can I guess from where to take city?

Comment: city is in another table, so would a join do to get value of the column city?

Comment: Yes, you shoud join table that is updated to another table where city is olaced

Comment: sorry, what do you mean , where city is placed?

Comment: What are you looking for in the table structure ? im using `sp_help tableName` query to get the information?

Comment: I do , im new to sql,  im just trying to understand what you need. is there a command I could run?

Comment: No just show which tables you have and columns there are in those tables.